# IPython magic commands work in Python console, but not in the "Run" or "Debug" script mode

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda, ipython

I have two python scripts `read.py` and `main.py`. The content of `main.py` is:

```
%run -i read.py
```

However, when I want to run the `main.py` as a script or debug it with icons in the upper right corner, I get the following error:

```
    %run -i read.py
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I edited the configurations of the `main.py` file so that its interpreter is Python version from conda environment. As in subject, I have no issues running this particular line `%run -i read.py` from Python console. What may cause this problem?

Comment: These commands are for the IPython console (=shell) only.

Comment: Yeah, but doesn't conda use ipython kind of natively? I have the same conda env specified for the PyCharm project level as for this particular `main.py` script when I run it, so I am not sure what's the difference.

Comment: IPython is a Python shell for input of simple Python expressions and commands. If a whole script is executed this is done by a standard Python interpreter (without support for these commands) IPython doesn't process these whole scripts. It can only start the interpreter and may postprocess exceptions if they occur to show them more nicely.